# Send input (command) with communicate to created Subprocess Python

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

I have created a Subprocess object. The subprocess invokes a shell, I need to send the shell command provided below to it. The code I've tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["code.exe","25"],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
print p.communicate(input='ping 8.8.8.8')
```

The command doesn't execute, nothing is being input into the shell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the stderr of your process?

Comment: Yes it is empty at all.I think

Comment: So your code.exe spawns a shell?

Comment: Yes, it spawns the shell

Comment: Wait, why are you printing the p.communicate function?

Comment: I see the output in this way

Answer (score 1):

If I simulate code.exe to read the arg and then process stdin:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "arg: $1"
echo "stdin:"
while read LINE
do
  echo "$LINE"
done < /dev/stdin
```

and slightly update your code:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cwd = os.getcwd()
exe = os.path.join(cwd, 'foo.sh')
p = Popen([exe, '25'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(input='aaa\nbbb\n')
for line in out.split('\n'):
    print(line)
```

Then the spawned process outputs:

```
arg: 25
stdin:
aaa
bbb
```

If input is changed without a `\n` though:

```
out, err = p.communicate(input='aaa')
```

Then it doesn't appear:

```
arg: 25
stdin:

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So you might want to look closely at the protocol between both ends of the pipe. For example this might be enough:

```
input='ping 8.8.8.8\n'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why does my subprocess die after I communicate with it once? In the second time it say: you're writing to a closed file.

Comment: If you submit a question showing your code it will be easier to answer. Ideally, you have logging in your child process to explain why it terminates.